# IBM-Watson academic trial not launching

Tags: windows-10, ibm-watson, dsx-desktop

I want to try IBM-Watson, however after downloading the installer and installing, IBM Watson Studio does not pop up.

OS: Windows 10 Home 64-bit

Does anyone have suggestions on how to solve this?

I already tried:
-'Run as administrator'
-Uninstalling, reinstalling
- Downloading the installer again